# Keras_tuner nonsense ValueError: Unknown initializer: relu

Tags: python, keras

I am running a hyperparameter search on a new version keras tuner for a NN, and I get an error that 1) didn't exist in the old one, 2) doesn't make sense.

ValueError: Unknown initializer: relu. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument.

1. I don't get why 'relu' is passed as initializer, the code breaks at the definition of learning rate (as per keras tuner documentation):

```
hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
            loss=self.loss_function,
            metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy', 'accuracy'])
```

However, it works with

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
            loss=self.loss_function,
            metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy', 'accuracy'])
```

2. I am not specifying any weight initializers, so they all should be default ones.

Any idea why this could be happening?
thank you very much in advance!